# Mobile app screen scroll by description is not working

Tags: javascript, scroll, appium, webdriver-io

const scrollCommand = `android=new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().description(\"${locator}\"))`

I am trying to use above command to scroll the mobile app but currently it is just scrolling to the top and then scrolling one view down.

Its not able to scroll to the expected element with description sent to this method in element locator

```
try {
const ele = await find(locator, 1)
ele.scrollIntoView()} catch (e1) {
const scrollCommand = `android=new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().description(\"${locator}\"))`
let currentNumberOfViews = 1
while (currentNumberOfViews <= maxNumberOfViewsToScroll) {
  const elem = await $(locator)
  if (await elem.isDisplayed()) {
    return true
  }
  if (browser.capabilities.platformName.toLowerCase() === 'android') {
    await $(scrollCommand)
  } else {
    await scrollNViews(1)
  }

  currentNumberOfViews++
}
logSuccess(locator)
return false
```

}